# 403 'serving limit exceeded' but have 'Unlimited requests/second/user'

Tags: limit, quota, google-shopping-api

We utilize the Content API for Shopping to make updates to our product data.  We do this several times a day, and have done so for just over 2 months.

We made several successful calls today, but then started receiving the following:
Google API Error Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "servingLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Serving Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Serving Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

That lasted about an hour, then we made successful calls for a bit, then started getting errors again.

Checking the Google API Console -both Quota and Reports, we have 'Unlimited requests/second/user' for the all aspects of this API.

Is there an API issue?  If we are exceeded a quota, we do not see what that is.

Comment: This is probably something you should contact Google about - they know their APIs better than anyone else!